# Is there a way to know the email of "parent" in battle net account

Tags: battle.net

I want to test auction house in Diablo III. It says that I am blocked by my "parent"

I am 35 years old. There is no way there is a parental control there. Even if there is, I'll just sign in as parent and open it.

I keep asking for email to get the parental control but I never get any email. Not to my main Battle.net account. Maybe it's sent to the so called "parent's" email. But what's the parent's email? Who knows.

I asked Battle.net support. It's been more than 2 days with no answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you've entered the email yourself, there is no real way to know what the Parental Controls email is.

I would suggest contacting support again, preferably by phone. I had the exact same problem that you did, in that I was prevented from posting on the D3 beta forums because my Parental Controls settings disallowed me. I tried to get the email, but like you, it never came to my inbox. This was not simply a case of Parental Controls not being set up, as they *were*, but I was not receiving the email.

After calling Blizzard Customer Support, they told me that my Battle.net account had apparently been compromised. Seeing as I'm not a WoW player and had no other assets to steal, whomever had hacked my account had decided to change my Parental Controls settings and email ("to be mean", in the words of the Support Representative).

This sounds potentially like the same thing, so I would urge you to contact support by phone ([US info](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/contact), [EU info](http://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/contact)). Make sure you know the answers to your account security questions, and I would consider securing your account further with an [authenticator](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-authenticator-faq), if you don't already have one.

Comment: You're saying that those support will never answer? I'll all them.

Comment: @Jim I'm not saying that a written support ticket will *never* answer, but given your circumstances, a phonecall with support would likely be more expedient and allow you to skip the hassle of emailing all your account verification back and forth before you can get the problem fixed.

Comment: They answered but then they said it's because of some bug in auction house causing delay. Their customer support don't even read the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt much you can do by yourself im afraid. However if you want the case solved faster give them a call either by phone or skype.

http://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/contact

Good luck.